# Why does powershell script from inno setup print spaces between each two characters?

Tags: powershell, encoding, inno-setup

I am running a powershell script from my inno setup installer via the command:
`[Run]
Filename: {cmd}; Parameters: "/c powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -File ""{app}\InstallScripts\powershellScript.ps1""`

and transcribing my commands/output to a text file by running the command:
 `StartTranscript -Path $logFile` at the beginning of my script.

But in my log file which records all the commands/output I get really weird spaces between each pair of characters like so:

```
W i n d o w s   P o w e r S h e l l   T r a n s c r i p t   S t a r t 

S t a r t   t i m e :   2 0 1 8 1 0 0 8 1 3 5 9 1 7 

U s e r n a m e     :   D a v i d
```

But when I run the script manually I get the printings to the file normally, without the weird spaces.

Why is this happening and how can I correct it so when I run the script from my installer it will print the commands/output normally without these spaces between characters?

Comment: The transcript log is encoded as Unicode. What version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: By  running the command $PSVersionTable.PSVersion I can see that my version is v2.

Comment: Try converting the file to ASCII with `Get-Content -Path $logfile | Out-File -FilePath asciilog.log -Encoding ascii`.

Comment: Did you compare headers of the transcript logs? Can you post them here? How **exactly** do you *"run the script manually"*? What is your version of Windows? Btw, why do you run `powershell.exe` via `cmd.exe`?

Comment: I just compared the headers. When I run the script manually I get: ***** Windows PowerShell Transcript Start. Start time: 20181008153032. Username: David. Machin: David (Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1) . **** and when I run the script from inno setup I get the same header only with space between each character. When I run it manually I mean that I open cmd.exe and type the same command from the inno setup script. Does it matter if I run powershell.exe from cmd.exe?

Comment: OK, but is the output completely the same, not only those first two lines? - Btw, ihose are not a spaces, those are NULL characters. The file is in UTF-16 encoding. - It *should not* matter that you use `cmd.exe`, but it's just another layer that can cause troubles, so I'd remove it.

Comment: The output is completley the same, except for these NULL characters.

Comment: Hi @Davis8988 did you ever get to the bottom of this? I am seeing a similar issue where powershell behaves differently when called by Inno Setup. Any solution you found may also apply to my issue

Comment: Sorry but no. I gave up on **StartTranscript** command for my logging. I created my own log-file and saved it's path as a variable in my inno setup-script, and passed it to all my powershell scripts executions. I used **Add-Content** to append to it from each script.